# Fixed points of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fixed-points

My assignment is to determine fixed points of the differential equation

$$\frac{dN}{dt} = \left(\frac{aN}{(1+N)} - b -cN\right)N$$ where $a,b,c > 0$ and find out their stability.

I do understand that concerning differential equations, a fixed point is defined as  the $N$ which solves the equation $N = f(N) \cdot N$. For some reason I cant even start since I only get rubbish when trying to solve for $N$ from the equation. Any suggestions where to start?

Comment: I'm not sure about your definition of fixed-point. I would consider the fixed-points to be the values $N^*$ that solve $\Phi(N^*,t) = N^*\ \forall t$, where $\Phi$ is the flow-map of the ODE. And note that the fixed-points will coincide with the equilibrium-points, i.e. if your ODE is $\frac{dN}{dt}=f(N)$ then we have $f(N^*)=0$. In your case, $f(N^*)=0$ is just a cubic polynomial.

Comment: I dunno if fixed points in evolutionary models differ from the fixed points in ODE. We previously had a different model where the fixed point was calculated also as values $N^{*}$ which satisfy $N=f(N) \cdot N$ since the original equation is  $\frac{dN}{dt}=f(N) \cdot N$